# CheckBox Jquery - Prompt Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I had this working previously but for some reason it has stopped working, a syntax error I presume. Can anyone spot the issue?

I have had it running with the html inserted into the source on a browser and Jquery in a console. But not in JSFiddle and a few other options.

It should prompt when ticked and prompt again if unticked:

```
<td class="icon">
            <input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox">
    </td>


    $("#my_checkbox").click(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        this.checked = confirm('Are you sure you want to CONFIRM the order and EMAIL THE CUSTOMER?'); 
      }    
      else {
        this.checked = !confirm('Do you really want to change this to NOT RECEIVED?'); 
      }  
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thdbfuhs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without jquery

```js
$("#my_checkbox").click(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('my_checkbox').checked) {
    this.checked = confirm('Are you sure you want to CONFIRM the order and EMAIL THE CUSTOMER?');
  }    
  else {
    this.checked = !confirm('Do you really want to change this to NOT RECEIVED?');
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="icon">
        <input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox">
</td>
```

with jquery

```js
$("#my_checkbox").click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    this.checked = confirm('Are you sure you want to CONFIRM the order and EMAIL THE CUSTOMER?');
   
  }    
  else {
    
     e.preventDefault();
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="icon">
        <input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox">
</td>
```

Comment: This looks good, Is there any way I could disable the unticking of the box once it has been checked?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ")" before semicolon at the end of your JavaScript in the JSFiddle. JavaScript pasted in your question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery.js in your html first. then try below "tested" code.

```
$("#my_checkbox").on("click",function() {
  if ( $(this).is(':checked')) {
  alert("checked");
  } else {
  alert("Not checked");
}
});
```